# How do I learn about unknown children exiting in Go on Unix/Liunx?

Tags: linux, go, child-process

It doesn't look like Go has a way to register a signal handler, so I can't catch `SIGCHLD`. So, how do I learn about a process exiting that I may not known about because my process has its CHILD_SUBREAPER flag set or is PID 1 in a PID namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register signal handlers using [signal.Notify](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#example_Notify)

Comment: Oh! That's too simple! I was wondering why there was so much in `syscall` about signals but seemingly no way to listen for them. I will learn to navigate the library documentation one of these days.

Comment: I shouldn't have accepted your answer so soon, though waiting for the week and a half for me to discover this doesn't seem reasonable either. The problem is that the Notify mechanism tells you all about which signal you got, but none of the other details. So when you get the SIGCHLD telling you that you have a new child, you aren't told what it's PID is. :-(